# C++ Is there a way to get getline to read 2 numbers in a line separated by a space?

Tags: c++

I need my program to read these numbers:

```
4
42 5
47 6
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
//5sk3u
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int f,d,s; //f=4, d=42, then 47, s=5, then 6
    string line;
    ifstream myf ("Data.txt");
    (getline (myf,line));
    f=std::stod (line);
    getline (myf,line);
    d=std::stod(line);
    getline (myf,line);
    s=std::stod(line);
    cout << f << endl;
    cout << d << endl;
    cout << s;         //I'll make a loop for the final program, but right now this part isn't working
}
```

I don't understand how to get s=5 instead of s=47. I'm new to this and by reading through other solutions I couldn't understand anything, since there was too much new info. What's the easiest way to do this that's close to my existent code? Thanks for the help.

Edit: Here is my task."Chickens are being sold at a market. The chicken data is written in the file "Data.txt" with the number of chickens for sale on the first line and the subsequent lines showing the chicken's mass and age. Write a program that will find and print the original chicken's data in the results file "Results.txt"." 
The result needs to look like this: "Chicken numbr.1: mass:42 age:5" and so on for all the chickens.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::istringstream`? If not, see your C++ textbook for examples.

Comment: `Too much new information.` Maybe you need to try something easier first? Anyway `std::istringstream` is the way that is closest to what you have already. Read the lines into a string, and then read the numbers from the string (using `std::istringstream`).

Comment: IMO you are trying do something more complicated then needed and ask us to fix your incorrect approach. Please provide information what this program suppose to do instead how you are trying to do it, to make this question easier to answer.

Comment: I don't know how to use std::istringstream and I don't have a textbook, since I'm learning by completing the tasks my teacher gave us. Can someone tell me which parts I can ignore from here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/

Answer (score 0):

If this is some online problem solver do not make this over-complicated.
Just read this this way:

```cpp
int main()
{
     int n, age, mass;
     std::ifstream chickensFile("Data.txt");
     chickensFile >> n;

     for(int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
         chickensFile >> mass >> age;
         std:cout << "Chicken numbr: "<< /* do it yourself */;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'll give you the problem, sorry if it's a bit hard to read. I'm not a good translator. "Chickens are being sold at a market. The chicken data is written in the file "Data.txt" with the number of chickens for sale on the first line and the subsequent lines showing the chicken's mass and age. Write a program that will find and print the original chicken's data in the results file "Results.txt"." 
The result needs to look like this: "Chicken numbr.1: mass:42 age:5" and so on for all the chickens.

Comment: please edit your question to improve it instead posting comments here.

Answer (score 0):

You can read words that are separated with whitespace from file like this:

```
    ifstream file("Data.txt");
    std::string word;
    while (file >> word)
    {
        std::cout<< word << '\n';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Asked my friend and we made this together:

```
int a,x,z,n,f,j;
fstream fd;
fd.open ("Duomenys.txt");
n=0;
f=0;
j=z+1;
fd >> a;
while (n<a){
fd >> x >> z;
cout << x << " " << z << endl;
if (x>f){f=x;}
if (z<j){j=z;}
n++;}
cout << f << endl;
cout << z;
```

Problem solved.